# How to adapt a LaTex beamer theme to apply it in an rmarkdown::beamer_presentation

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, markdown, beamer

I would like to apply a `LaTex beamer theme` in an `rmarkdown::beamer_presentation`.
The custom themes contains a `beamerthemeTHEMENAME.sty`, `beamercolorthemeTHEMENAME.sty`, `beamerfontthemeTHEMENAME.sty`, `beamerinnerthemeTHEMENAME.sty`, `beamerouterthemeTHEMENAME.sty`.
If the template is sourced within my YAML header, the knitted presentation does not look very close to a beamer presentation generated straight from LaTex by applying the custom theme.

Thus, which contents of the `beamertheme*.sty` to modify or enhance the presentation require modification or need to be moved from the `beamer theme`, e.g. to `template.tex` and `includes`*?

In particular, I am struggling on using the following frame templates defined in `beamerouterthemeTHEMENAME.sty`: `\titleframe`, `\tocframe`,  `\closingframe`

For the footline defined in `beamerouterthemeTHEMENAME.sty`, it would be very nice to have a hyperlink from the logo to the `table of contents` slide (like the page numbers are linked to the `appendix`).
An MWE is provided below. Any help is greatly appreciated.

#### MWE.Rmd

````
---
title: "MWE"
subtitle: "Beamer presnetation with R-markdown"
institute: "some place"
date: "`r format(Sys.time(), '%B %d, %Y')`"
output:
  # beamer_presentation: default
  bookdown::pdf_book:
    base_format: rmarkdown::beamer_presentation
    # includes:
    #  - in_header: preamble.tex
    theme: "THEMENAME"
    latex_engine: xelatex
    toc: false
    slide_level: 2
---


​```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
​```

# Random presentation

## TOC - Table of Contents {.unnumbered}

\tableofcontents
\label{contents}

## Slide with Bullets

- Bullet 1
- Bullet 2
- Bullet 3

## Apendix
\appendix
````

#### beamerthemeTHEMENAME.sty

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

% Tizk, textpos, graphics
\RequirePackage{tikz}
\RequirePackage{textpos}
\RequirePackage{xcolor}
\RequirePackage{booktabs}

% Beamer settings
\usecolortheme{THEMENAME}
\useoutertheme{THEMENAME}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\mode<all>
```

#### beamercolorthemeTHEMENAME.sty

```
\mode<presentation>
\definecolor{THEMECOL}{RGB}{162,48,47}  % red
\definecolor{THEMEgray}{RGB}{110,110,101}% gray

\colorlet{titlefgcolor}{THEMECOL} % color of box
\colorlet{titlebgcolor}{THEMEgray} % color of box

\setbeamercolor*{title}{fg=THEMECOL}    % presentation title 
\setbeamercolor*{author}{fg=THEMECOL}   % author
\setbeamercolor*{date}{fg=THEMECOL} % date
\mode<all>
```

#### beamerouterthemeTHEMENAME.sty

```
\mode<presentation>

% Redefine \insertshortinstitute to allow multiple lines
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\insertshortinstitute}{\beamer@shortinstitute}
\makeatother

% Title frame
\def\titlefigure{img/my_bg}
\newlength\titleboxwidth
\setlength{\titleboxwidth}{0.33\textwidth}
\newcommand{\titleframe}{%
    {
        \setbeamertemplate{background}{
            \begin{tikzpicture}
            \useasboundingbox (0,0) rectangle(\the\paperwidth,\the\paperheight);
            \ifx\titlefigure\empty
                \fill[titlebgcolor] (6.3mm,6.4mm) rectangle (\the\paperwidth-8.3mm,\the\paperheight-13mm);
            \else
                \node at (current page.center) [anchor=center,yshift=-3.5mm] {\includegraphics[width=\the\paperwidth-19mm]{\titlefigure}};
            \fi
            \node at (current page.north east) [anchor=base east, xshift=-8.3mm, yshift=-6.3mm, align=left, inner sep=0mm, font=\fontsize{5.5}{6.6}\selectfont] {
                \insertshortinstitute
            }; 
            \node at (current page.north west) [anchor=south west, inner sep=0mm, xshift=8.3mm, yshift=-8.6mm] {
                \includegraphics[height=3.8mm]{img/my_logo}
            }; 
            \end{tikzpicture}
        }
        \setbeamertemplate{footline}{}
        \begin{frame}[noframenumbering]
            \begin{tikzpicture}
                \useasboundingbox (0,0) rectangle(\the\paperwidth,\the\paperheight);
                \node [
                    shift={(-11.5mm,-1.8mm)},
                    fill=titlefgcolor,
                    minimum width=0.46\paperwidth,
                    minimum height=18mm,
                    anchor=west,
                    inner sep=4mm
                    ] at (current page.west) {
                        \hspace*{9mm}
                        \begin{minipage}{\titleboxwidth}
                            \raggedright
                            \usebeamerfont{title}\usebeamercolor[fg]{title}\inserttitle\\[3mm]
                            \usebeamerfont{author}\usebeamercolor[fg]{author}\insertauthor\\
                            \usebeamerfont{date}\usebeamercolor[fg]{date}\insertdate
                        \end{minipage}          
                    };
            \end{tikzpicture}
        \end{frame}
    }
}

% TOC frame
\newcommand{\tocframe}{%
    \begin{frame}
      \frametitle{Outline}
      \tableofcontents
    \end{frame}
}

% Section title frame
\AtBeginSection[]
{
    \begin{frame}
      \frametitle{Outline}
      \large
      \tableofcontents[currentsection] 
    \end{frame}
}

\newenvironment{closingframe}{
    \setbeamertemplate{background}{
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \useasboundingbox (0,0) rectangle(\the\paperwidth,\the\paperheight);
        \node at (current page.north west) [anchor=base west, xshift=8mm, yshift=-10mm, align=left] {
            \includegraphics[width=23mm]{img/my_logo.png}
        }; 
        \end{tikzpicture}
    }
    \setbeamertemplate{footline}{}
    \addtolength{\headsep}{10mm}
    \begin{frame}[noframenumbering]
}%
{
    \end{frame}
}%

% Footline
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{
    \leavevmode%
    \hyperlink{contents}{\includegraphics[width=12mm,trim=0mm 0.4mm 0mm 0mm]{img/my_logo.png}}
    \hfill
    \hyperlinkappendixstart{\insertframenumber/\inserttotalframenumber}
    \vspace{3mm}
}

\mode<all>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make the following dirty hacks to the markdown document:

- Instead of the yaml title, use `\AtBeginDocument{\title{MWE}\titleframe}`  to suppress the annoying automatic title markdown inserts (which does not even uses `\maketitle`, so one can't make any reasonable modifications) and add your custom title command
- `\AtEndDocument{\begin{closingframe}lalala\end{closingframe}}` to add your closing frame [replace lalala with whatever text you like]
- add `\makeatletter\beamer@ignorenonframefalse\makeatother` to suppress options markdown annoyingly automatically uses and which don't allow any wrappers for frames
- you can use

  ````
  ``` {=latex}
  \end{frame}
  \tocframe
  \begin{frame}
  ```
  ````

  to use your `\tocframe` macro, however I don't see much use for this, as markdown will automatically insert such frames at all reasonable places (and then a couple of more at all unreasonable places as well, just because it seems to enjoy being annoying...)

---

````
---
subtitle: "Beamer presnetation with R-markdown"
institute: "some place"
date: "`r format(Sys.time(), '%B %d, %Y')`"
author: "Donald Duck"
output:
  # beamer_presentation: default
  bookdown::pdf_book:
    base_format: rmarkdown::beamer_presentation
    # includes:
    #   in_header: preamble.tex
    theme: "THEMENAME"
    latex_engine: xelatex
    toc: false
    slide_level: 2
    keep_tex: true 
header-includes:
  - \AtBeginDocument{\title{MWE}\titleframe}    
  - \AtEndDocument{\begin{closingframe}lalala\end{closingframe}}
  - \makeatletter\beamer@ignorenonframefalse\makeatother
---

# Random presentation

## TOC - Table of Contents {.unnumbered}

\tableofcontents
\label{contents}

``` {=latex}
\end{frame}
\tocframe
\begin{frame}
```

## Slide with Bullets

- Bullet 1
- Bullet 2
- Bullet 3

``` {=latex}
\end{frame}
\appendix
\begin{frame}
```
## Apendix
````

Now to the theme:

- if your tex distribution has been updated at one point since the dinosaurs gone extinction, then you don't need `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`. That's the default in current latex distributions. Also rmarkdown will automatically insert this.
- you don't need `\RequirePackage{xcolor}`. Not only does beamer already load this automatically, but it will also be included in this annoyingly long list of unsuitable packages rmarkdown automatically adds  to the document.
- The `\titleframe` macro also needs a couple of modifications because the theme does abuse `\\` for line breaks and does not test if title, author and date macros are actually filled. Combined this will fail spectacularly...
- you might also want to use different colours for the background and the font of the title box.... I mixed a bit of white to the background to make the font visible

```
\newcommand{\titleframe}{%
    {
        \setbeamertemplate{background}{
            \begin{tikzpicture}
            \useasboundingbox (0,0) rectangle(\the\paperwidth,\the\paperheight);
            \ifx\titlefigure\empty
                \fill[titlebgcolor] (6.3mm,6.4mm) rectangle (\the\paperwidth-8.3mm,\the\paperheight-13mm);
            \else
                \node at (current page.center) [anchor=center,yshift=-3.5mm] {\includegraphics[width=\the\paperwidth-19mm]{\titlefigure}};
            \fi
            \node at (current page.north east) [anchor=base east, xshift=-8.3mm, yshift=-6.3mm, align=left, inner sep=0mm, font=\fontsize{5.5}{6.6}\selectfont] {
                \insertshortinstitute
            }; 
            \node at (current page.north west) [anchor=south west, inner sep=0mm, xshift=8.3mm, yshift=-8.6mm] {
                \includegraphics[height=3.8mm]{example-image}
            }; 
            \end{tikzpicture}
        }
        \setbeamertemplate{footline}{}
        \begin{frame}[noframenumbering]
            \begin{tikzpicture}
                \useasboundingbox (0,0) rectangle(\the\paperwidth,\the\paperheight);
                \node [
                    shift={(-11.5mm,-1.8mm)},
                    fill=titlefgcolor!50!white,
                    minimum width=0.46\paperwidth,
                    minimum height=18mm,
                    anchor=west,
                    inner sep=4mm
                    ] at (current page.west) {
                        \hspace*{9mm}
                        \begin{minipage}{\titleboxwidth}
                            \raggedright
                            \usebeamerfont{title}\usebeamercolor[fg]{title}\inserttitle\par
                            \usebeamerfont{author}\usebeamercolor[fg]{author}\insertauthor\par
                            \usebeamerfont{date}\usebeamercolor[fg]{date}\insertdate
                        \end{minipage}          
                    };
            \end{tikzpicture}
        \end{frame}
    }
}
```

For the footline, use the hyperlink target that is created by your toc section

```
% Footline
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{
    \leavevmode%
    \hyperlink{toc---table-of-contents}{\includegraphics[width=12mm,trim=0mm 0.4mm 0mm 0mm]{example-image}}
    \hfill
    \hyperlinkappendixstart{\insertframenumber/\inserttotalframenumber}
    \vspace{3mm}
}
```

[I guess the number of times I used `annoying` in this answer shows how much more difficult rmarkdown makes a job that would have taken 2 seconds in a normal beamer document]

Comment: Thank you so much for your elaborate answer which was helpful! I wonder why adding `compact-title: false` is needed (title prints well if I leave it out and just use `\AtBeginDocument{\titleframe}`.

Comment: @mavericks  `compact-title: false` was just a remnant from trying to convince rmarkdown to avoid the automatic title page without such dirty hacks as removing `title: ...`, but it stubbornly refused corporate ...

Comment: OK, understand. Despite setting `toc: false` markdown yet magically prints the TOC (once, if setting `toc: true` I get it twice), so I left out `\tableofcontents
\label{contents}`as well as ````{=latex} ...`. However, the hyperlink target to the TOC I cannot get to work (no matter if I in/exclude the just mentioned manual TOC stuff).

Comment: Indeed, you are right with the "annoying parts" :)
R markdown just allows me to easily reuse the data analysis or output from reports in a  presentation. This makes it reproducible and streamlines the sizes/resolution of contents in figs and tables.

Comment: if I use your code the presentation contains a blank page between the title frame and the TOC and right after the TOC. Any ideas why and how to resolve? Interestingly, one cannot use any `includes` while using the custom theme (title page becomes emptied), thus one has to move any additions into the theme itself.