# Create a hyperlink from the logo to the table of contents slide in an rmarkdown::beamer_presentation with a custom beamer theme

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, markdown, beamer

I use a custom `LaTex beamer theme` in an `rmarkdown::beamer_presentation`.
As per these SO answers ([LaTex theme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66230673/how-to-adapt-a-latex-beamer-theme-to-apply-it-in-an-rmarkdownbeamer-presentati), [colon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66244765/how-to-escape-a-colon-in-the-header-includes-in-a-yaml-header/66245172?noredirect=1#comment117120479_66245172), [theme path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66230695/specify-paths-to-custom-theme-preamble-and-includes-in-yaml-header-of-beamer-pr/66257573#66257573)), I used several modifications of the YAML header and `beamerthemeTHEMENAME.sty`.
These LaTex hacks are necessary to apply the `LaTex Beamer theme` smoothly in the `rmarkdown::beamer_presentation`.

For the foot line defined in `beamerouterthemeTHEMENAME.sty`, it would be very nice to have a hyperlink from the logo to the `table of contents` slide (like the slide numbers are linked to the `appendix`).

[image: Logo Linked to ToC]

#### What I tried: define custom foot line in `beamerouterthemeTHEMENAME.sty`

```
\mode<presentation>

...

% Foot line
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{
    \leavevmode%
    \hyperlink{toc---table-of-contents}{\includegraphics[width=12mm,trim=0mm 0.4mm 0mm 0mm]{img/my_logo.png}}   
    \hfill
    \hyperlinkappendixstart{\insertframenumber/\inserttotalframenumber}
    \vspace{3mm}
}

\mode<all>
```

For a complete MWE, see my [SO question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66258624/remove-additional-blank-slides-after-toc-and-insert-black-slides-in-rmarkdownb).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In normal beamer code, you could simply attach a label to the frame, but Rmarkdown seems to be too stupid to correctly parse the square brackets in `\begin{frame}[label=outline]`.... annoying!

As a workaround you could use something like a section name for which markdown will automatically insert a label:

````
---
subtitle: "Beamer presnetation with R-markdown"
institute: "some place"
date: "`r format(Sys.time(), '%B %d, %Y')`"
author: "Donald Duck"
output:
  # beamer_presentation: default
  bookdown::pdf_book:
    base_format: rmarkdown::beamer_presentation
    # includes:
    #   in_header: preamble.tex
    theme: "THEMENAME"
    latex_engine: xelatex
    toc: false
    slide_level: 2
    keep_tex: true 
header-includes:
  - \AtBeginDocument{\title{MWE}\titleframe}    
  - \AtEndDocument{\begin{closingframe}lalala\end{closingframe}}
  - \makeatletter\beamer@ignorenonframefalse\makeatother
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
```

## Outline {.unnumbered}

\tableofcontents

# section

## Slide with Bullets
<!-- ======================================================== -->

- Bullet 1
- Bullet 2
- Bullet 3

<!-- Appendix -->
<!-- ======================================================== -->
``` {=latex}
\end{frame}
\appendix
\begin{frame}
```
````

and use this target in the footline

```
% Footline
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{
    \leavevmode%
    \hyperlink{outline}{\includegraphics[width=12mm,trim=0mm 0.4mm 0mm 0mm]{example-image}}
    \hfill
    \hyperlinkappendixstart{\insertframenumber/\inserttotalframenumber}
    \vspace{3mm}
}
```

Comment: Copied your code 1:1 and yet the hyperlink to ToC is not working... annoying Rmarkdown :(

Comment: @mavericks Is the code compiled two times? rmarkdown seems to have some very erratic behaviour concerning the number of compilations

Comment: That was likely the reason! Thanks so much for the hint!