# Specify paths to custom theme, preamble and includes in YAML-header of beamer presentation generated with R markdown

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, markdown, beamer

In a beamer presentation generated with `rmarkdown::beamer_presentation`, my aim is to apply a custom theme, which contains a `beamerthemeTHEMENAME.sty` (with sub files `beamercolorthemeTHEMENAME.sty`, `beamerfontthemeTHEMENAME.sty`, `beamerinnerthemeTHEMENAME.sty`, `beamerouterthemeTHEMENAME.sty`), as a  `template.tex` and *Includes*.

Currently I source these files in the YAML-header as follows:

```
theme: "THEMENAME"
template: template.tex
includes:
  in_header: preamble.tex
  before_body: before_body.tex
  after_body: after_body.tex
```

To organize the presentation and its files more neatly, I would like to move these files ...

- to a subfolder of the presentation directory (*short-run solution*)
- to a general folder such the templates can likewise be sourced by/applied to other presentations (*long-term solution*).

How would I have to adjust the YAML header in each case to correctly source the above-mentioned files?

Answer (score 0):

Meanwhile, I found an answer which works for the short run.
(For [hints regarding a long-term solution, see the answer from](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66225779/10451245) @Steven and comments by @Samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz.)

- Drop all files of the custom theme `THEMENAME` as well as any includes (e.g., `preamble.tex`) into a subfolder termed `beamer_files` within the folder in which the Rmd file of the presentation is located in.
- Modify the YAML header and `beamerthemeTHEMENAME.sty` as shown below.
  As per these SO answers ([LaTex theme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66230673/how-to-adapt-a-latex-beamer-theme-to-apply-it-in-an-rmarkdownbeamer-presentati), [colon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66244765/how-to-escape-a-colon-in-the-header-includes-in-a-yaml-header/66245172?noredirect=1#comment117120479_66245172)), some LaTex hacks are necessary to apply the `LaTex beamer theme` smoothly in the `rmarkdown::beamer_presentation`.

#### MWE.Rmd

````
---
# COMMENT out "title" in YAML header: else markdown generates a second title page
# ==> if title contains no special characters: feed it straight into LaTex at the end of the YAML header
# ==> if title contains special characters, like ":", feed it in "preamble.tex" sourced in "LaTex Hacks"
subtitle: "Beamer presentation with R-markdown"
institute: "some place"
date: "`r format(Sys.time(), '%B %d, %Y')`"
output:
  # beamer_presentation: default
  bookdown::pdf_book:
    base_format: rmarkdown::beamer_presentation
    # Source below in "LaTex Hacks", if want theme to be stored in subfolder (else rmarkdown does not find it)
    # theme: "THEMENAME"
    # Source "includes" below in "LaTex Hacks" if using custom theme with custom title page
    # => else, markdown places the includes at inadequate position in LaTex file, which then either does not show the title or throws an error
    # includes: ...
    latex_engine: xelatex
    toc: false
    slide_level: 2
classoption: aspectratio=169 # fix aspect ratio of presentation (169 => 16:9, 149 => 14:9, default: 4:3)
#
# LaTex Hacks
# --------------------------
compact-title: false # to remove markdown generated title frame
header-includes:
  # - \title{Title if no special characters} 
  - \input{beamer_files/beamerthemeTHEMENAME.sty}
  - \input{beamer_files/preamble}       # feed title to LaTex in preamble.tex due to ":"
  - \def\titlefigure{img/my_bg}
  - \AtBeginDocument{\titleframe} # add title frame defined in beamerouterthemeTHEMENAME
  - \makeatletter\beamer@ignorenonframefalse\makeatother
  ---


​```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
​```

<!-- TOC - Table of Contents -->
<!-- ======================================================== -->

``` {=latex}
\end{frame}
\tocframe
\begin{frame}
```

## Slide with Bullets
<!-- ======================================================== -->

- Bullet 1
- Bullet 2
- Bullet 3

<!-- Appendix -->
<!-- ======================================================== -->
``` {=latex}
\end{frame}
\appendix
\begin{frame}
```
````

#### beamerthemeTHEMENAME.sty

```
% WAS:
% \usecolortheme{THEMENAME}
% \useoutertheme{THEMENAME}
% NOW:
\input{beamer_files/beamercolorthemeTHEMENAME.sty}
\input{beamer_files/beamerouterthemeTHEMENAME.sty}

\mode<all>
```

#### preamble.tex

```
% "title" is commented out in YAML header: else markdown generates a second title page
% if title contains no special characters: feed it straight into LaTex at the end of the YAML header
% if title contains special characters, like ":" or a forced linebreak feed it to LaTex here:
\title[short version]{First line of the title:\par second line of the title}
```

Comment: You must not abuse \\ for line breaks

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz so use `\newline`to force the break instead?

Comment: Given the context, I would use `\par`